# Not able to remove substring that is variable from a string

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I want to remove everything except for **Name**. `removeStart()` and `remove()` don't seem to take variable as a parameter.

```
String tmpField  = '{!Contract.Name}';

String child = 'Contract';

tmpField = tmpField.removeStart('{!'); // Works

tmpField = tmpField.remove(child); // Doesn't seem to work - remove() or removeStart()

tmpField = tmpField.removeStart('.');

tmpField = tmpField.removeEnd('}');
```

Please let me know if any other ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

for this kind of task [regex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm) is the best instrument to use. Here is a [link to test regex](https://regex101.com/r/LRqUd8/1) for your needs. You can also read an explanation for regex:

```
"(!Contract.)(.*)(?=})"
    1st Capturing Group (!Contract.)
        !Contract matches the characters !Contract literally (case sensitive)
        . matches any character (except for line terminators)
    2nd Capturing Group (.*)
        . matches any character (except for line terminators)
        * matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    Positive Lookahead (?=})
Assert that the Regex below matches
    } matches the character } with index 12510 (7D16 or 1758) literally (case sensitive)
```

**Apex:**

```
String objectToMatch = 'Contract';
String stringToFind = '{!Contract.Name}';
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(!' + objectToMatch + '.)(.*)(?=})');
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(stringToFind);
if(mat.find()){
    System.debug(mat.group(2));
}
```

**Debug:**

> |DEBUG|Name

---

In this case, you can control for which object you need to parse a field from the input `String`.

Comment: The main problem I have is matching with a variable, and that didn't work for me when I tried removeStart() and remove(). I might have tried Regex already. I will give it another go and see.

Comment: @ApexCowboy what do you mean by "matching with a variable" ? Can you update your question with another example, of what is an input and what should be as an output? the provided answer works correctly to get the field name.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi Instead of matching with 'Contract', I want to match with a variable that contains the string 'Contract'. In my example, String child = 'Contract';

Comment: @ApexCowboy I've updated the answer to parse field based on the object name. Please check.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi `Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(\\{\\!Contract.)(.*)\\}');` works, but with variable `Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(\\{\\!'+ child +'.)(.*)\\}');` doesn't work for me.

Comment: you are using an incorrect regex. please check the answer.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi
I tried the answer regex, didn't work for me. What I don't understand is why "Contract" works in my previous reply `('(\\{\\!Contract.)(.*)\\}');`, but the variable version doesn't `('(\\{\\!'+ child +'.)(.*)\\}');`. Is there a syntax error where I replace the string with a variable?

Comment: @ApexCowboy if you tried, what you have copied in the comment above - you haven't tried regex from my answer. They are different.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi I tried your regex `Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(!' + objectToMatch + '.)(.*)(?=})');` and doesn't work for me. The exact string Contract works however `Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(!Contract.)(.*)(?=})');` I don't think the regex is where the problem is, it's the syntax used to match with a variable.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi I also System.debug the variable before and after the regex to make sure it says Contract - `USER_DEBUG [70]|DEBUG|"Contract"` Could it be the double quotes that may have impacted the Pattern?

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi I think your answer is right for the example above. I am discovering that the argument for the parameter in my original code might not be clean and have came with double quotes. I'm investigating.

Comment: @ Oleksandr Berehovskyi Update: It is the double quotes - working now after that is fixed. Thanks